# Adding an item to nested lists

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> Children { get; set; }
}
```

From a parent I can have multiple Children, and each of those children can have more children, etc.

Now my aim is to populate this object/list in a hierarchical form. I start with the top and slowly add onto it so that it branches out, however I have an issue. How can I find and add an item to a particular child?

Edit:
Several methods have been provided to find that node and add to that node. However this issue remains:

Consider this: I have a Parent which already has a few children. I will use the Find method to find one of these children and this method with return a Child. Now I need to add a new child to that child in my parent. When I used your code, it added the Child to the Child that the method Find returned, however it did not affect my original Parent. The list of children of that Parent was still 0 when I wanted it to have the child that I newly added.

Drawn out example: This is the list that I already have

```
- Mary    
    - Peter
        - Jake
    - Luke
```

In this example, Mary has two children, Peter and Luke. Peter has a child, Jake. My aim is to find Jake and a add a child to Jake. I can do this by using a recursive search and that will successfully return Jake. I can add a child (John) to Jake and that will leave me with this:

```
- Jake
    - John
```

However I need to modify the original parent so that I will have:

```
- Mary
    - Peter
       - Jake
           - John
  - Luke
```

Comment: What do you mean by a particular child? How do you search for it currently?

Comment: I'm not sure how to search for it currently, I will know the name of the Child but it can be several levels into the nested list already. I wish to find out the best way to search for that child and to add onto that child's list.

Comment: Do you want to add the new child as a child of the `Parent` by `Name`? Or to the parent of the `Parent`?

Comment: Edited it with an example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to recursivly search for your node in the tree:

```
public static Parent FindNode(int id, Parent current)
{
    if (current.Id == id)
    {
        return current;
    }

    foreach (var child in current.Children)
    {
        var ret = FindNode(id, child);
        if (ret != null)
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

usage example (`root` represents the root node of your tree):

```
var node = FindNode(myId, root);
if (node != null)
{
    node.Children.Add(newChildren);
}
```

Comment: This code works however you are only adding to that node and not to the list itself, since the children of that list remains empty. My aim is to add to the node in that list.

Comment: @NetUser101 what do you mean by "not to the list itself"? The children will be added to the list via `Add`?

Comment: Currently i am searching through the entire parent hierarcy to first find the matching node, which the code above successfully does. After finding the matching node, I need to FIND that node in the same list to add items to it. Your code adds to the node alone and not the node that is actively part of the list.

Comment: ok, you mean you want to search only one level deep after that? Maybe `matchingNode.Children.Single(n => n.Id == myId).Children.Add(newChildren)` does the trick for you?

Comment: Consider this: I have a Parent which already has a few children. I will use your Find method to find one of these children and this method with return a Child. Now I need to add a new child to that child in my parent. When I used your code, it added the Child to the Child that the method Find returned, however it did not affect my original Parent. The list of children of that Parent was still 0 when I wanted it to have the child that I newly added.

Comment: @NetUser101 I updated my answer. Now the function returns a tuple: item1 is the found children and item2 is the parent of that child

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127165/discussion-between-netuser101-and-heinzbeinz).

Answer (score 0):

you will have to write a recursive function to do it. You will first get the children for the top most Parent then pass the children as argument to the below function "GetParendetails"

```
   public Parent GetDetails()
   {
       //the following code should be replaced by the code to get Top parent details from your db or whatever. pass the children of this class to the below function
      Parent P=new Parent();
      P.Id=1;
      p.Name="Top";
      P.Children=new List<Parent>();
      P.Children.Add(new Parent(2,"test1"));
      P.Children.Add(new Parent(2,"test2"));
      P.Children.Add(new Parent(2,"test3"));
      P.Children=GetParendetails(P.Children);

   }


   public List<Parent> GetParendetails(List<Parent> PL)
   {
      if(PL!=null)
      {
          foreach(Parent P in PL)
          {
             List<Parent> childlist=new List<Parent>();
              //logic to get children of P and adding them to childlist
               P.Children=GetParendetails(childlist);
          }
      }
      return PL;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your items should contain a `ParentId` property then you can use LINQ to build the tree

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> Children { get; set; }
}
```

To build the tree just use LINQ

```
public IEnumerable<Item> BuildTree( IEnumerable<Item> source )
{
    // build the children list for each item
    foreach ( var item in source )
    {
        item.Children = source.Where( i => i.ParentId == i.Id ).Tolist();
    }
    // return only the root parents
    return source.Where( i => i.ParentId == 0 ).ToList();
}
```